# VBA - to call values from a vector defined in different macro

Tags: vba, excel

My problem is following - I have a vector defined in one macro and I try to call the values from the vector in another macro. Despite the fact that all the objects are public, the second macro does not cooperate with the vector. Thank you for any suggestions which way to go.

My code is following:

```
Public qj As Integer
Public pp_ii(5) As Variant

Public Sub Loop_over_pp()
 Dim myarray As Variant
    pp_ii = Array(51, 52, 53, 54, 55)
    For qj = 0 To UBound(pp_ii)
       Call Macro1
    Next qj
End Sub

Public Sub Macro1()
  Worksheets("List1").Range("A" & qj) = pp_ii(qj)
End Sub
```

Comment: If it's a dependency, it should be a parameter. Just pass the array to the second `Sub` instead of using a global.

Comment: Change `Public pp_ii(5) As Variant` to `Public pp_ii() As Variant` and it works for me.

Comment: Using @ScottCraner's idea, you can take out the `(5)` in your Public declaration, change `For qj = 0` to `For qj = 1`, however this messes with the output. To compensate, add `Array(0, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55)`. This will skip the first object in the `Array`, but will give you your desired output.

Comment: @ScottCraner  thank you for advice, it works now.

Comment: Please do not change the code in the question.  It makes the question invalid and will not help future searchers.  Now the code works and it will confuse those that come later.

Comment: If you want to show the corrected code that is working post it as an answer, again for future viewers.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, corrected

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
Public qj As Integer
Public pp_ii() As Variant

Public Sub Loop_over_pp()
  pp_ii = Array(51, 52, 53, 54, 55)
  For qj = 0 To UBound(pp_ii)
   Call Macro1
 Next qj
End Sub  

Public Sub Macro1()
Worksheets("List1").Range("A" & qj + 1) = pp_ii(qj)
End Sub
```